# Application crash on UIButton click : iphone

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a View base iphone application
I add a NSObject class **AddNewContact** and take its object in IB

**AddNewContact.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface AddNewContact : NSObject {
}
-(IBAction)abc:(id)sender;
@end
```

**AddNewContact.m**

```
#import "AddNewContact.h"

@implementation AddNewContact

-(IBAction)abc:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"this is test");
}
@end
```

I bind a UIButton action to abc: on clicking the button application crashes, even NSLog is also not logged
but if I bind the button action to other classes function then it working ok

Crash Log

```
2011-06-08 15:40:30.368 myApp[5466:207] -[NSCFString abc:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b7b1c0
2011-06-08 15:40:30.416 myApp[5466:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString abc:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b7b1c0'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02ad9b99 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02c2940e objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x02adb6ab -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x02a4b2b6 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x02a4ae72 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   UIKit                               0x0039e7f8 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    6   UIKit                               0x00429de0 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x0042c262 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
    8   UIKit                               0x0042ae0f -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
    9   UIKit                               0x003c23d0 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
    10  UIKit                               0x003a3cb4 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
    11  UIKit                               0x003a89bf _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7672
    12  GraphicsServices                    0x0306a822 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x02abaff4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x02a1b807 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x02a18a93 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x02a18350 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x02a18271 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x0306900c GSEventRunModal + 217
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x030690d1 GSEventRun + 115
    20  UIKit                               0x003acaf2 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    21  myApp                           0x00001fa4 main + 102
    22  myApp                           0x00001f35 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Can anybody tell me where I am wrong

Thanks
**Amit Battan**

Comment: Did you connect the button correctly?

Comment: Well i think that you are not initializing your button properly, or you are over releasing it that is causing the problem. You paste your code for initializing so that we can have a look at it

Comment: @Anne yes I connect it correctly in IB .. @robin I am using button through IB so I don't think it releasing

Comment: other is IB part... If I bind the button to already working function of other class then it works ok .. but if I bind it abc: then it crashes ...even I tried to make new class then also same issue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will be releasing your AddNewContact view controller, the view is still in the superview but the viewController is released, the button tries to call 'abc' on AddNewContact controller which no longer exists...

Comment: @Simon thanks for your response .. can you tell me where/when `AddNewContact view controller` is released.. as its object in IB

Comment: Can you add the code where you create and show the AddNewContact view controller?

Comment: I ahve take Object in IB and change its class ..check images ... http://i.stack.imgur.com/iJJhs.png . . . http://i.stack.imgur.com/CC7Zz.png ... and never user AddNewContact any where in project .. just bind the button action only

Comment: You are setting the class on what? A UIViewController element in InterfaceBuilder? How is that class getting loaded? Without a valid class instance to call the method on you will get an error....

Comment: i am not setting it as viewcontroller . just simple NSObject ... also am using other class as this which are working ok .. may be I am wrong .. can you please tell me how I do it

Comment: Ok, so you have to create an instance of a view controller to use it...either programmatically or via interface builder... check this tutorial...http://chris-software.com/index.php/2009/04/29/creating-a-view-programmatically/

Comment: @Lee I have add AddNewContact in my main view controller and IBOutLet its object and bind it.. then it works fine ..

Comment: That is fine if you prefer the 'visual' method of using Interface Builder. I personally prefer to do more in code only relying on IB when I have a complex layout for a single view controller, I tend not to use the UIViewController components in IB but they are there to be used if you find that easier! Good luck!

Comment: Hi Lee one more question if I have to add new view and want to call from AddNewContact then how I have to add this ... `[self.view addSubview:newView];` **this code in the class AddNewContact** it not working ... can you please suggest me

Comment: done with `[[viewControllerObject view] addSubview:newView];` . . then working .. is it proper way

Comment: Yes that is correct, you can also do [viewControllerObject.view addSubview:newView];

Comment: means basically all view can be controlled through viewController class as its name refer

Comment: The view is simply a property of the view controller. It is the view controllers responsibility to manage that view BUT you can access the view to decide where to show it, add it to YOUR subviews etc.